# Image viewer for .is2 files

Tags: images, viewer

Is there an image viewer capable of displaying images in .is2 file format?

These images were taken using a Fluke termographic camera.

At Fluke's site they offer their Smartview software for this kind of images, but I'm searching for a free (as in "free beer" ;-) alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Could you not convert the image to a different type? i.e. JPG or TIFF if you want to keep the quality.

Comment: Verboten -- This is asking for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Fluke SmartView is the program to use, as this file type is proprietary to Fluke
http://www.fluke.com/fluke/usen/Accessories/Software/Fluke-SmartView-IR.htm?PID=56169

Answer (score 1):

as [here](http://www.file-extensions.org/is2-file-extension) is mentioned
The default software that works with is2 file format:

> IRT Cronista
>   Company or developer: 
>     GRAYESS Inc.`

Comment: The format isn't unique to fluke. This is a better link. http://www.grayess.com/software/irt-cronista/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll your own, here are some matlab functions to read this kind of image.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27915-fluke-is2-file-reader/content/read_is2.m

and

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32352-readis2-import-is2-files-fluke-infrared-camera/content/readis2.m